# Display an image in menu generated from taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, routes, panels, theming

I am using Drupal 7 with Taxonomy and Taxonomy Field Menu to generate a menu based on taxonomy terms (Categories) - including node links (the terms themselves are not linked, just the nodes, in case this is important somehow). I am using this menu in Panels in two panes.

I need to display an image alongside the nodelinks (just one per taxonomy term) and this image needs to be easily replaceable from the backend. The menu is supposed to look like this:

```
- Home
- Taxonomy Term 1
    - Node
    - Node
    - Node
    [Image for Term 1]
- Taxonomy Term 2
    - Node
    - Node
    - Node
    [Image for Term 2]
- Taxonomy Term 3
    - Node
    - Node
    - Node
    [Image for Term 3]
```

The views module is not really an option, as I don't have enough time to work through and understand 30 chapters of "Taming the Beast". It may pay off in the long run, but there simply isn't enough time for views at the moment. Any alternative approaches are welcome.

Comment: Try the [Taxonomy Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image) module. I don't know whether it meets your requirement or not. But make sure to test it on test env as it's in Dev version.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan yes this is a good module to try!

Comment: Ok, I'll make it as answer. So that it may helpful for future readers. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Taxonomy Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image) module

> The taxonomy_image module allows site administrators to associate images with taxonomy terms. With the association created, an admin can then make a call to 'taxonomy_image_display()' from their theme or other PHP code to display the appropriate image.

Comment: Since it may be useful to someone else, I'll upvote. However, seeing how the D7 version is still an early dev release, we decided that it'd be a terrible idea to use it in production at this point. Thank you for the answer, though. We'll have to see if there is a different module/way to achieve this.